# Newer Boost Library Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ros, boost, library, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I am having a little issue linking a newer version of Boost (1.46.1) against ROS Electric in Lucid (10.04).

I have specified the newer version for the ROS environment using.

```
ROS_BOOST_VERSION=1.46.1
```

and

```
ROS_BOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/include/
```

I have also removed every trace of boost 1.40

However when I try to compile a package.. joy for example.  I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_signals.so.1.40.0, needed by 
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/lib/libsensor_msgs.so, 
not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12792/newer-boost-library-ubuntu-10.04/) by [KM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1699/km/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-01-27

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1699/km/) on 2012-01-27**:
Ok, I tried recompiling from the source.  It again tries to install libboost1.40-all-dev from the in the install script.. Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
#Packages ['libboost1.40-all-dev']
sudo apt-get install libboost1.40-all-dev
}}} I said no and it stopped installation.

**Comment by [KM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1699/km/) on 2012-01-27**:
I had previously wiped and reinstalled from the debian.. This of course packaged boost 1.40 because of the lucid install.  Shall I try reinstalling everything again but from source? edit: Do I need to do anything special when compiling from source?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-01-27**:
Are you recompiling everything from source? Have you made sure that you have cleaned all packages before rebuilding with the new version of boost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As Tully said the main fix is to recompile ROS from source (Thanks Tully).

Here are the few things that I did before hand to get it to compile accordingly and stop throwing the errors.  These may not all be necessary.

edit your bashrc to export the following.

```
#In my case the boost 1.46.1 library was located in /usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" 
#I also wanted to explicitly tell the ROS environment my boost location
export ROS_BOOST_ROOT="/usr/local/"
export ROS_BOOST_VERSION="1.46.1"
```

I then followed the intructions for compiling from source at [ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source)

You may also want to preclean any package that you are recompiling.

```
rosmake --pre-clean
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [KM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1699/km/) with karma: 66 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2